# Twilio Voice Timestamps

Tags: flutter, dart, twilio, webrtc, rtp

Our application uses the Twilio voice SDKs for iOS, Android, and Web. Our use case relies on precise device synchronization and time stamping. We are playing an audio stream on multiple adjacent devices (in a Twilio conference call) and we need that audio playback to be in sync. Most of the time, it works great, but every now-and-then, one of the devices falls a little bit behind and throws off the whole experience. We want to detect when a device is falling behind (receiving packets late) so we can temporarily mute it so it does not throw off the user experience we are going for.

We believe that Twilio voice uses real time communication (web RTC) and real-time transport protocol (RTP) under the hood. We also believe RTP has time stamping information for when packets are sent out and when packets are received.

We are looking for any suggestions for how we might read this timestamp information (both sent & received) to detect device synchronization issues.

Our iOS and Android clients are built using Flutter & Dart, so any way to look at this packet information using Dart would be great. If not, we can use native channels through Swift and Kotlin. For the web, we would need a way to look at this timestamp data using javascript.

If possible, we'd like to access this information through the SDK. I don't see anything about timestamps in Twilio's voice documentation. So, if not possible, we might have to sniff for packets on the devices? This way, we could look at the RTP packets coming from Twilio to see what information is available. As long as this does not break Twilio terms of service, of course :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could get this information I don't think it will be useful. The `timestamp` field in RTP has little to do with real time. In voice it's actually a sample offset into the audio stream. With a typical narrowband codec with a fixed bit rate and no silence suppression it's completely predictable from the RTP sequence number. For example, with 20ms packets of G.711 it will increment by exactly 160 each packet.

RTP receivers expect there to be random variation between the receipt time of a packet and its timestamp - known as jitter. This is introduced by delays at the sender, in the network and at the receiver. This is why receivers use jitter buffers to reduce the likelihood of buffer underrun on playing. The definition of jitter for RTCP - [the interarrival jitter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#section-6.4.1) - is a calculation that measures this. That is - the variation between the (predictable) RTP timestamp and the measured wallclock time at the receiver.

Maybe you need something more like an NTP protocol between your client and your server.

Comment: Thank you, this answer gave me a lot of pointers we need to look into. We are trying to play an audio stream in-sync through many adjacent devices (in the same room). The way we plan on using the timestamp information is to mute a device from playing audio if we can detect that it is receiving packets later than adjacent devices, until it gets back in sync. Do you have further suggestions given that use case?

Comment: The problem with most 'good' jitter buffer implementations is that they are adaptive: the more jitter and delay they encounter, the more buffering they add, with the effect of adding a little more delay between packet receipt and delivery to the sound card. So if one of your devices encounters a short glitch in transmission it will compensate by temporarily increasing the delay through its jitter buffer - which sounds like the exact opposite of what you want. You may want to implement your own stack and jitter buffer which is intolerant to delay (introduces silence instead).